# Automatic object numeric key assignment

Tags: javascript

When creating an array, we can ignore the key field and let JavaScript generate the keys for us in order starting from 0 upwards.

```
var color = ['green', 'blue', 'red', 'yellow', 'purple'];
```

Which we can access like

```
alert(color[0]);  //green
```

I want to create a object with numeric keys, but I would rather not define them explicitly, is a similar method possible?

I have tried

```
var color = {'green', 'blue', 'red', 'yellow', 'purple'};
console.log(color);
```

But this doesn't work as expected, returns **SyntaxError: missing : after property id**

Comment: As I know you cannot create an object without key:value pairing.

Comment: An object with Numeric keys is best replaced by an Array. Why you'd need something like that? As far as I have understand you want this `{1:"green", 2:"blue"}` ??

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I need to check if a key exists, which I saw in other posts was best done with if(key in obj)... Rather than if(typeof = undefined via an array

Comment: You can check it with `1 in color`.

Comment: @torazaburo *"with 1 in color"* with a object or array? or both?

Comment: @gummage both. An array is an object too.

Comment: `1` is a key and `color` is an object. Arrays are sort of gussied-up objects with special management of the `length` property, and methods such as `pop`, but still objects at heart.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think its possible. According to W3C definition javascript object:

JavaScript objects are containers for named values.

Named values are written as name:value pairs (name and value separated by a semicolon).

The name:value pairs, in JavaScript objects, are called object properties.

Hence you cannot do so. Either use an loop to create such a situation. Eg:

```
var obj = {};
for(var i = 0; i < length; i += 1) {
    obj[i] = color[i] ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not possible. It is just the way js objects are.

Can't you just iterate over the array and put the data inside an object?

```
var color = ['green', 'blue', 'red', 'yellow', 'purple'];
var colors_obj = {};

for(var color_num_key in color) {
    colors_obj[color_num_key] = color[color_num_key];
}

console.log(colors_obj);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/k6nkr732/)

Answer (score 0):

If you insist, @canon's `reduce` solution and @Fyre's manual solution are both fine, but also:

```
$.extend({}, color)                 // jQuery
_.extend({}, color)                 // Underscore
Object.assign({}, color)            // ES6
LIB.extend_like_api({}, color)      // all other libraries in the world
```

Essentially what all these do is remove the "array-ness" of the array.